# WordPress: how to display only certain post types on page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm developing a multimedia oriented theme for WordPress.

Upon entering the site, the user is supposed to choose to view MUSIC or VIDEO CLIPS side of the website. If he chooses VIDEO CLIPS then only the video clips custom post type should be displayed. And if he chooses MUSIC, only the music custom post type should be displayed throughout the website.

Once the user is in, he will have switcher buttons in the top navigation. There he can choose to browse music or video clips.

I'll not be using the multisite function.

What's the best way for me to display only certain custom post types according to the user's choice?

Comment: Be more specific please, with which part are you having trouble to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is fairly vague however I will try to point you in the right direction based on what you are asking.

Firstly you should create two custom post types: `music` and `video`. To learn how to do that, please read the following reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

I would suggest you then create two page templates, one called 'Music page', and other called 'Videos page'.

You should then create two pages, 'music' that uses your 'Music page' template and 'videos' that uses your 'Videos page' template. The new pages are created via WP Admin -> Pages -> New Page.

In the Music page template, you should have a `WP_Query` that takes args, one of which is the music custom post type.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'music'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In the Videos page template, you would have a WP_Query that takes args, one of which is the video custom post type.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'video'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Of course, after you create the query you should then traverse the query with the use of a while loop, if the query has posts. To learn more about how to do that, please read this reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

To learn more about page templates, please read the following wordpress.org link:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

I hope this points you in the right direction.